# Очередное создание объекта абстрактного класса

Tags: java, классы

Есть такой код:

```
abstract class AClass{
    public void abc() {
    System.out.println("Wow!");
    }
}

public class Demo{   

    public static void main(String[] args){
        AClass tmp = new AClass() {};
        tmp.abc();
    }
}
```

и он работает. Нигде не нашел информации, во что именно превращают фигурные скобки этот объект.

Как еще, кроме как объект абстрактного класса `AClass`, можно интерпретировать объект `tmp`?

Comment: Данная конструкция создаёт объект анонимного класса, который неявно наследуется от вашего абстрактного класса.

Comment: обычно в абстрактном классе задают методы, логику которых нужно определить в наследниках. У вас таких нет, потому и фигурные скобки пустые.

Comment: Если вы сделаете Sytem.out.println(tmp.getClass()), то увидите, что у вас другой класс.

Comment: абстрактный класс не может иметь объектов.

Answer (score 4):

Данная контрукция, а она называется "*аннонимный класс*":

```
AClass tmp = new AClass() {};
```

Превращается в обычный. Если вы скомпилируете его и посмотрите какие файлы получились, то обнаружите еще один файл примерно с таким названием - `<Имя внешнего класса>$<Числовой суффикс>.class`.

Предсказать точное имя вы не можете, поэтому вызвать у него конструктор или что то еще не получится. Единственный экземпляр данного класса будет присвоен переменной `tmp`.

Интерпретируйте `tmp`, как объект наследника `AClass`